# Join two SQL queries with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Database In this Database a seasons has multiple programs recorded and multiple songs are performed/recorded in the program, also a song has multiple musical keys and Musician and Band members Uses Instruments.

Below are the normalized tables of my Database

```
seasons -> season_id(pk), name
programs -> program_id(pk), name
programs_recorded -> p_id(pk), season_id(fk), program_id(fk)
songs -> song_id(pk), title
songs_performed -> s_id, song_id(fk), program_id(fk)
musical_keys -> song_id(fk), music_keys
musician -> musician_id(pk), name, song_id
band -> band_id(pk), song_id(fk), band_name
band_member -> member_id(pk), band_id(fk), member_name
instrument -> instrument_id, instrument_name 
musician_plays -> m_id(pk), musician_id(fk), instrument_id(fk)
member_plays -> mem_id(pk), instrument_id(fk), member_id(fk)
```

Note: A song is performed in program by  Musician, Band so songs primary key is in  musician and band as foreign keys, also Musician and Band uses Instruments to record songs. Band has band members.

My Query is: For a specific record, list all the instruments and the key notes(musical keys) that have been used to produce the record?

Note: My record is my Program_id, as each program is recorded in a season.

Now here are my queries which I want to join:

```
SELECT
    programs.program_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT instrument_name),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT music_keys)
FROM
    seasons
    INNER JOIN programs_recorded ON seasons.season_id=programs_recorded.season_id
    INNER JOIN programs ON programs_recorded.program_ID=programs.program_ID
    INNER JOIN songs_performed ON programs.program_ID=songs_performed.program_ID
    INNER JOIN songs ON songs_performed.song_id=songs.song_id
    INNER JOIN musical_keys ON songs.song_id=musical_keys.song_id
    INNER JOIN band ON band.song_id=songs.song_id
    INNER JOIN band_member ON band_member.band_id=band.band_id
    INNER JOIN member_plays ON member_plays.member_id=band_member.member_id
    INNER JOIN instrument ON  member_plays.instrument_id=instrument.instrument_id 
WHERE
    songs_performed.program_id=12000
GROUP BY songs_performed.program_id;
```

Join this query with

```
SELECT
    programs.program_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT instrument_name),
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT music_keys)
FROM
    seasons
    INNER JOIN programs_recorded ON seasons.season_id=programs_recorded.season_id
    INNER JOIN programs ON programs_recorded.program_ID=programs.program_ID
    INNER JOIN songs_performed ON programs.program_ID=songs_performed.program_ID
    INNER JOIN songs ON songs_performed.song_id=songs.song_id
    INNER JOIN musical_keys ON songs.song_id=musical_keys.song_id
    INNER JOIN musician ON musician.song_id=songs.song_id
    INNER JOIN musician_plays ON musician_plays.musician_id=musician.musician_id
    INNER JOIN instrument ON musician_plays.instrument_id=instrument.instrument_id
WHERE
    songs_performed.program_id=12000
GROUP BY songs_performed.program_id;
```

Both the queries give me the correct result but separately, I don't know how to join them and print the result through one query

Note: Song is connected with songs_performed , musician and band table.

Can Anyone join these queries? 
If anyone have any confusion about my design please feel free to ask.

Comment: Are you simply looking for a `UNION ALL` ?

Comment: I don't know where exactly can I Write union all. I have used musician and musician_plays in 1st query  and band , band_member , member plays in the 2nd query.

Comment: Take a moment to look up where a `UNION` keyword goes, please. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/union.html

Comment: Ahh You are a Life savor . I just wrote Union All between the two queries and I got my desired result I couldn't join them because I think its impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Posted as an answer on behalf of the OP:*

The problem's solved. I just wrote `Union All` between the two queries and it worked.